# in React Native, How to change Android app icon "dynamically"?

Tags: android, react-native, npm, icons

I looked up on the internet and found some packages like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dynamic-app-icon) which doesn't support React Native Android and [this](https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon) which not well documented...

*Are there any other modules for React Native Android for that? Or is there any way i can program app to change the icon dynamically.*

**For example,** when dark theme for system, icon changes to dark theme. Or like a calendar icon changes showing current date on icon. Or clock showing hands movement as seconds goes by, etc.

Comment: Are you found anything helps?

Comment: not yet  @OliverD

Comment: Are there any news?

Comment: You can write an android code to change app icon and create a bridge with react-native to call the method. Here are few example of how it's changes in android code - [Dynamic launcher icon](https://medium.com/@simonmisles/dynamic-launcher-icon-and-name-for-android-e40bf0561715)  ,  [Change launcher icon dynamically](https://mobikul.com/change-launcher-icon-dynamically-in-android/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few steps to enable dynamic icon change on Android. **Seems a lot of work, but actually very easy**.

**1. Put all your icons on `mipmap` folder.**

**2. `AndroidManifest.xml`** (Create activity alias for each icon)

Under `<application>`, Main `<activity>` should not contain `intent-filter` & `android:exported` should be set to `true`. this will make `MainActivity` available always without showing shortcut icon.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Test App"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true"
>
</activity>
```

**3. Now, for each icon you want to display, create `<activity-alias>`. Set `android:enabled` to `true` for your defailt icon.** All enabled icons will be displayed on desktop. So make sure you enable only one activity alias.

```
<activity-alias
    android:label="Test App :: Default"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon1"
    android:name="First"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
android:label="Test App :: Special"
android:icon="@mipmap/icon2"
android:name="Second"
android:enabled="false"
android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>

<activity-alias
    android:label="Test App :: Very Special"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon3"
    android:name="Third"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

**4. Create a Java Classes**

Create empty class for each of your activity alias.

```
package com.your.package;

class First {
}
```

**5. Create IconChanger class**

`@ReactMethod` allows accessing it from react-native. You can change `com.your.package` to `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` to avoid writing your package name multiple times.

```
package your.package.name;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class IconChanger extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public IconChanger(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "IconChanger";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void changeIcon(String enableIntent, String disableIntent, Promise response) {
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = this.reactContext.getPackageManager();
            int action;
            String activeIntent="com.your.package."+enableIntent;

            Toast.makeText( this.reactContext,"Enabling "+enableIntent,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName("com.your.package", activeIntent), 
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            );

            if(!disableIntent.equals(null) && !disableIntent.equals(enableIntent)){
                activeIntent="com.your.package.."+disableIntent;
                Toast.makeText( this.reactContext,"Disabling "+disableIntent,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    new ComponentName("com.your.package.", activeIntent), 
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                );
            }
            response.resolve(enableIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.reject("Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**6. Register it as NativeModule**

Create `CustomPackages.java`

```
package com.your.package;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomPackages implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
            ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new IconChanger(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }
}
```

**7. Now add this package to your `MainApplication.java`**

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    packages.add(new CustomPackages());
    return packages;
}
```

**8. Access `IconChanger` from `react-native`**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { IconChanger } = NativeModules;
IconChanger.changeIcon(newIcon, oldIcon);
```

**[NOTES]**

- **This will enable new activity & then close old activity.**
- **Change icon on app close or in background, as changing activity closes the app.**

Comment: this seems a very complete answer to this question. Can you tell me what would be the proper icon sizes for different resolutions on the mipmap folders? (btw, I think you meant "mipmap" instead of "minimap" right?)

Comment: @CarlosZinato Sorry for the typos. 
icon sizes should be.
xxxhdpi(192 x 192), xxhdpi(144 x 144), xhdpi(96 x 96), hdpi(72 x 72), mdpi(48x48)

Comment: You can also consider using this package that handles this native logic behind the scenes: https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon

Comment: What about iOS?